# How do I make a draggable, sortable list display something else while it's dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've been messing around with sortable lists with jQuery ui, and am unsure of how to temporarily adjust the element that's being dragged to something that's generic when dragging to sort.

If the elements you are sorting are very large, it becomes awkward to drag a large element. It would be easier to see if you were instead dragging some sort of text that said "List Item" that was smaller.

Example code:
HTML:

```
<div>Sortable List 1
<ul class="sortableList">
    <li class="ui-state-default large-box">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default large-box">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default large-box">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default large-box">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default large-box">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.large-box
{
  height:100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sortableList").sortable({
        revert: true,
        placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder',
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0jqwapg7/

Notice how the boxes are very large and this makes it sort of difficult to see when dragging. I want to use a generic smaller element temporarily (for example, a only 25px high text element that says "List Item") when dragging that makes it easier to see, then normal when dropped into place.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps, adding add new class to make element small when dragging and and when drag finished remove that class

jsfiddle here too for example https://jsfiddle.net/cfw5j1nz/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sortableList").sortable({
        revert: true,
        placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder',
        /*update: function (event, ui) {
            // Some code to prevent duplicates
        }*/

        start: function( event, ui ) { 
 /*         $(ui.item).removeClass("large-box"); */
            $(ui.item).addClass("small-box");
            },
       stop:function( event, ui ) { 
/*          $(ui.item).addClass("large-box"); */
            $(ui.item).removeClass("small-box");

    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sortableList").sortable({
        revert: true,
        placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
        start: function (event, ui) {
          ui.item.toggleClass("sortable-placeholder");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
          ui.item.toggleClass("sortable-placeholder");
        }
    });
});
```

you need set start and stop events and create a css for your placeholder

```
.sortable-placeholder {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: If I was dragging Item 1, I want that to instead be a small element that's being dragged. Not the styling of the location that it's going to be dropped. I realize I used the word placeholder here in two different meanings

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to set a function for `helper` and ideally to use it in conjunction with placeholder.

JS:

```
$(".sortableList").sortable({
    revert: true,
    helper: function(e, ui) { return $("<div class='helper'>List Item</div>"); },
    placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder'
});
```

CSS:

```
.large-box
{
  height:100px;
}

.helper
{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#333;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.sortable-placeholder
{
  height: 25px; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tq2c0f7w/